# Why Firebase Phone Authentication cannot Auto-Sign?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am implementing the `Firebase Auth` module to enable phone verification in my app. I set up everything according to the docs and everything works (I receive the SMS). But the **"Auto Sign-In"** doesn't work.
The android logs say this:

```
W/FirebaseAuth: [SmsRetrieverHelper] Timed out waiting for SMS.
I/PhoneAuthProvider: Sms auto retrieval timed-out.
```

Here is the method `verificationPassed()` which does the phone verification.

```
 private void verificationPassed()
    {
        _otpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                _phone = _otpUserNumber.getText().toString();
                _userName = _otpPassengerName.getText().toString();

                if(_phone.length() != 13)
                {
                    FancyToast.makeText(AuthActivity.this, "Wrong number", FancyToast.LENGTH_SHORT, FancyToast.ERROR, false).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    _otpButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    _progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    PhoneAuthOptions options =
                            PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(_firebaseAuth)
                                    .setPhoneNumber(_phone)
                                    .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                    .setActivity(AuthActivity.this)
                                    .setCallbacks(_callbacks)
                                    .build();
                    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);

                }
            }
        });

        _callbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks()
        {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential)
            {
                String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();

                Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + phoneAuthCredential);


                if(code != null)
                {
                    _otpNumberText.setOTP(code);
                    _otpButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    _progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e)
            {
                Log.w(TAG, Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
                if(e.getMessage().contains("We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later"))
                {
                    FancyToast.makeText(AuthActivity.this, "Device blocked due to unusual activity. try again later", FancyToast.LENGTH_SHORT, FancyToast.ERROR, false).show();
                }
                else if(e.getMessage().contains("A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred"))
                {
                    FancyToast.makeText(AuthActivity.this, "Network Error!", FancyToast.LENGTH_SHORT, FancyToast.ERROR, false).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    FancyToast.makeText(AuthActivity.this, "Verification failed. Try again", FancyToast.LENGTH_SHORT, FancyToast.ERROR, false).show();
                }
                _progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                _otpButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(@NonNull final String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken)
            {
                super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

                _progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                _otpButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                _otpUserNumber.setText(_phone);

                if(_otpNumberText.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && _otpNumber != null)
                {
                    _otpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            if(_otpNumber.isEmpty())
                            {
                                FancyToast.makeText(AuthActivity.this, "Enter sent code", FancyToast.LENGTH_SHORT, FancyToast.INFO, false).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                _otpButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                _progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                PhoneAuthCredential _credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(s, _otpNumber);
                                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(_credential);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check if it's the correct SHA key that you provided